# My circular saw won't cut straight

Tags: circular-saw

My circular saw, Riobi, tracks to the left.  Even with a guide clamped to the work piece I can't cut a straight line.  What's up with that?

Comment: Try tightening the nut that holds down your blade or it's possible your blade is warped a little which would cause the uneven cut meaning you'd need a new blade

Comment: I am shocked to here your having problems, I know this is irrelevant but I own a whole collection of Ryobi tools and never had a problem. But if all else fails contact them. There customer service is great and replaced a weed wacker I got without need of proof of purchase, which is gret because I never would have found that recite.

Comment: Thanks.  Blade is warped, but the nut is tight.  Off to get a new and better blade.

Answer (score 2):

I started out with a cheap Ryobi circular saw, and I had the same issue.  I eventually realized that the base plate was not parallel to the blade.

I would suggest taking a measurement from the edge of the base plate to the front of the blade and comparing it to the distance from the edge of the base plate to the back of the blade.  (For the most accurate measurement make sure you rotate the blade and measure to the same tooth both times.)  If they're not identical then you know that is the problem.

My solution was to throw it out and buy a track saw.

Comment: Measuring to the same tooth front and back is a great tip. It doesn't localise the cause to the base plate though, since you'll still get a different measurement with a slight blade wobble even if the baseplate is perfect (which generally they should be if made from a casting and not machined).

Comment: @Graphus The misaligned base plate on the saw I had was definitely stamped from sheet metal, not cast.  I didn't really bother tracking it down but I'd say the most likely cause of the inaccuracy was drilling the pivot holes that attached the plate to the saw.

Comment: Well if it's stamped then definitely scope for it to be out of square. Forgot they could be just stamped from sheet, which can make them flimsy to boot!

Comment: Plate is stamped, if a new blade doesn't fix the problem, it's off to the store for a return

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the Comments above this may be a duplicate of a previous thread and the replies there could help you solve the problem.

This isn't a diagnosis or a solution but a workaround that you may be able to take advantage of with the saw running exactly as-is.

- If your saw tracks to the left clamp the guide on the left side of the saw.

That way the current drift of the saw will pull it firmly against the guide board and not away from it, almost ensuring a straight cut. I believe a similar idea is used by some jigsaw owners, although jigsaws are lower in power and cut more slowly the basic principle may still work here.

Comment: Thanks, position of the guide board doesn't matter much.